# Can time reciprocity in special relativity be compared to the illusion of distant objects seen in the past? Why or why not?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Let's imagine there is a network of planets, all stationary in the same inertial frame, and we can ignore any relativistic effects and treat this universe as classical.

For the sake of coherent argument, we will pretend all planets are inhabited by humans in perfect mirror worlds, and they all think the date is 2000 AD.

They all see eachother's past. The further away they are from eacother, the further into the past they see. In fact, all other planets are in the past compared to them, all of them think they are the in the present and the others are in the past.

Events that one planet views as simultaneous are not viewed as simultaneous on another planet. For example take planet A, B, C, in that oder. Planet B sees planet A and C as 1950, with both of them fighting world wars (for example). But planet A sees themselves in 2000, planet B in 1950, and planet C in 1900. The simultaneousness of world wars depends on the location of the viewer.

This being said, if two planets slowly drift together at non relativistic speeds, they will realize they are in the same year as eachother, as they meet. This is why you can consider them seeing each other in the past to be an illusion.

You COULD consider all other planets but your own to ACTUALLY be in the past, but most humans would agree that should be considered an illusion. Just because we see them in the past doesn't mean they really are. If two planets meet or a space traveler goes to another planet, we can consider this illusion "resolved" and can consider all planets to be at the same date.

If two planets were together (at the same year) then drifted apart (now see eacothers past) and then drifted back together, they will both agree that when they saw eachother's past they were actually "in the same year" while apart.

This can be compared to the reciprical effects of time dilation in special relativity below:

Let's start over. There are now many observers moving in different inertial frames from eachother.

Each observer sees its time as "fastest" and the other observers's time as slower (just like they saw themselves as oldest in the first scenario).

They may also disagree on which events happen simultaneous, just as in the first example.

If two observers start in the same inertial frame, and then separate (we don't care which one accelerated in this example, they both could), they will see eachother's time as moving slower (similar to how to planets drifted apart now see eachother's past). However, if they return to the same inertial frame, they will now see their speed of time matching, while their absolute time is different (one aged more, the other aged less, they both agree).

Them returning to the same inertial frame guarantees that they now agree on who is older or younger, just like two planets meeting guarantees the date is the same.

Just like planets seeing eachother's past was an illusion that was solved by meeting, two observers returning to the same inertial frame resolves the illusion that both of their times were moving slower. They now agree on who is older.

If these observers never reach the same inertial frame of reference, they will ALWAYS see eachother's rate of time as slower, just like two planets that never meet will always see eachother's date as in the past.

But two observers who enter the same inertial frame will ALWAYS agree on who is now older, just like two planets meeting will always agree on the year they are in.

Just because we "see" something in the past, or "see" it's time moving more slowly, doesn't mean it is. These are both tricks caused by the unique properties of light.

If you agree that "seeing" other planets in the past can be resolved by meeting, and is an illusion, and you agree that "seeing" other observers time moving slowly can be resolved by entering the same inertial frame (regardless of who accelerates to achieve this), then how could anyone not count this as a similar illusion? (An illusion of the next order, similar to how acceleration is one order higher than speed).

PS, this is not denying relativity, or asking how it works. This is merely arguing that the reciprical effects we see from special relativity should be treated as an illusion. Please don't explain how special relativity works using analogies, that is not what this is about. I understand the math behind SR and the concept. This agrees that observers will both SEE eachothers time as slower AND have experienced different total times if they leave and then rejoin thr same inertial frames.

Comment: If the "illusion" is experienced by all beings, what makes it an illusion and not "reality"? This seems more of a philosophical issue than a physical one. That being said, I did not really understand what you were talking about here.

Comment: Thanks, Tobias. The illusion of all other planets being in the past is an illusion, even if we all pervieve it that way. (In real life not just my thought experiment). Why DO we consider it am illusion in that case? To better understand it.

Comment: Your problem is your definition of an illusion. You seem to consider an effect to be an illusion if it appears in one set of circumstances and not in another. That does not make the effect an illusion- it means that the magnitude of the effect is dependent on the circumstances.

Comment: You are arguing that just because time dilation is dependent on motion, and reduces to zero when motion stops, that it is an illusion. It is not illusory- it is a measurable effect. While you are moving relative to me, you are time dilated in my frame, and I am in yours. It is a geometrical effect of spacetime. If you stop moving, we are no longer time dilated relative to each other. An illusion is an effect you perceived but never existed- you are confusing an illusion with a temporary effect or an effect that depends on circumstances.

Comment: Instead of calling everyone here elitists, why not show us some actual calculations and prove to us all how right you are?  Put your money where your mouth is!  We can wait . . .

Comment: Everyone responding to this acted as if this question is denying the time altering effects of relativity, which it never does. I explicitly state that two objects that re-enter the same inertial frame will now be different ages. This question only goes to show the illusory properties of *reciprocal* time dilation, which will be resolved (unilatteral time dilation) once the objects are in the same inertial frame. I have reviewed no satisfactory answer as to why this viewpoint is "wrong". It's mathematically identical to the other viewpoint.

Comment: And marco... seeing distant planets in the past is a measurable effect. However, we consider this to be an illusion because we believe they are actually in the present, like us, we just can't see it. Or do you as well not consider seeing distant objects in the past as an illusion of sorts?

Comment: @Spencer you are still not getting the point. Time dilation isn't 'resolved' when objects stop moving relative to each other- time dilation ceases. By introducing symmetrical acceleration, you have undone the reciprocal effect, but that doesn't make the effect an illusion before you undid it. It's like saying 'I let the air out of my car tyres and the car dropped two inches in height, but it was an illusion because when I pumped the tyres up again the car went back to its usual height'.

Comment: As for seeing the planets in the past- we don't consider it to be an illusion!!!! It is a real effect. We are seeing the planets as they were. It would be an illusion if I thought the planets were like that 'now' and that the light from the planets had reached me instantaneously. An illusion is an effect you perceive but does not exist. The time lag associated with light from distant objects is not an illusion- it is an effect that exists.

Comment: What I don't understand is why you seem hell-bent on denying the existence of an effect that is baked in to the mathematics of the Lorenz transformation and therefore utterly inseparable from all the other aspects of SR. You either have to deny all of SR or you have to accept all of it.

Comment: "An illusion is an effect you perceive but does not exist." We perceive the planets to be in the past but that state no longer exists. I guess that is why I view seeing things that aren't there anymore as an illusion. If you would rather say that "what you *see* doesn't match what is *really happening right then*" then I'll accept that instead. In that case, then would you agree that in the reciprocal effects of relativity what you *see* doesn't match what is *really happening* since what you called below "worse than an illusion" will be resolved when two objects enter the same inertial frame?

Answer (score 3):

> Events that one planet views as simultaneous are not viewed as simultaneous on another planet. For example take planet A, B, C, in that oder. Planet B sees planet A and C as 1950, with both of them fighting world wars (for example). But planet A sees themselves in 2000, planet B in 1950, and planet C in 1900. The simultaneousness of world wars depends on the location of the viewer.

No. Planet B sees events from 1950 going on on planets A and C, but knows that A and C are 50 light years away, and so knows that it was 1950 there 50 years ago. The people on planet B know that light does not travel instantaneously, and therefore don't believe that what they *see* is what is happening *now*. They correct their image of the world for the propagation time delay. Likewise for planets A and C. Everybody corrects their view for propagation delays, and so, in this non-relativistic universe, they all perceive time on the other planets to be perfectly synchronised.

> If you agree that "seeing" other planets in the past can be resolved by meeting, and is an illusion, and you agree that "seeing" other observers time moving slowly can be resolved by entering the same inertial frame (regardless of who accelerates to achieve this), then how could anyone not count this as a similar illusion? (An illusion of the next order, similar to how acceleration is one order higher than speed).

I don't agree that seeing other planets in the past is a problem that needs resolving. It only becomes an illusion if you falsely believe light propagates instantaneously. And I don't agree that seeing other observers' times moving slowly is a problem in need of resolving either, or an illusion. Again, it only appears to be a problem because of faulty assumptions.

I get the impression you are trying to construct some sort of loose analogy to justify calling time dilation an "illusion", which lots of people do to avoid having to admit that time doesn't work how they thought it did. There's really no need. It's just geometry.

There's an equivalent behaviour in Euclidean geometry that everyone is familiar with, and that makes for a much better analogy. Several people walk across a field at the same speed. Each of them defines two coordinate axes at right angles to one another: 'forwards' (time) and 'sideways' (space). Two of them observe their neighbour is drifting slowly away from them in the 'sideways' direction (i.e. they're moving through space), and drifting slowly *backwards* in the other coordinate (i.e. progressing more slowly through time). *Both* people see the other drifting backwards. Their partner's progress through 'time' is slower.

Is that an illusion? It depends what you mean by that. It's not an illusion in the sense of saying that the other person is not where they appear to be. It's not caused by propagation delays, or atmospheric refraction, for instance. The actual reason that *both* can claim the other is progressing more slowly in the 'forwards' direction is that they are using different definitions of 'forwards'. They are distances measured along different axes. And if you understand that relatively-moving observers progressing through spacetime are measuring time *along different time axes,* it is no longer a surprise that they get different answers. The *illusion* is their false impression that the definitions of 'forwards' and 'sideways' - time and space - are universal.

Two people walking at the same speed in slightly different directions *both* see the other moving slower than themselves, steadily falling behind. There is no physical force resisting their motion. The physics of their walking is no different. Moving clocks are not slowed by any change to the physics of the clockwork's motion. But neither is the other person actually walking abreast, and this appearance that they are behind you some sort of light-bending illusion. Nor is this effect some sort of unexplainable magical distortion of the natural order requiring you to abandon common sense. You just have to adjust your geometric intuition slightly.

The big problem with your comparison is that it gets reality and illusion the wrong way round. The non-relativistic world where everyone measures time along the same spacetime direction is the illusion. The reality is that everyone measures time along their own worldline, and *by that measure* the moving clocks of their companions *do indeed* run more slowly. Pick some different coordinate axes, and the values of the coordinates change.

Science popularisers have a tendency to make special relativity sound stranger, more mysterious, and more difficult to understand than it really is. It makes science sound cool and interesting, and scientists sound really clever, which makes the kids want to grow up to be scientists too. Pointing out that if you walk in different directions, you both end up behind the other, and this is basically the same thing, makes it sound obvious and trivial. But the trouble with making it sound incomprehensibly strange is that it doesn't help you to give up the real illusions.

Comment: If you don't think seeing other planets is an illusion, then yes it follows that the reciprical portion of relativity would also not be considered an illusion by you...

Comment: However, if you DO consider seeing planets in the past as an "illusion" then you could also consider the reciprocal portion of SR as an illusion and my question still stands. It's undeniable the two phenomena are comparable (in the same way the concepts of speed and acceleration are comparable).

Comment: If I insisted that distant planets really *were* in the past, and didn't just appear to be that way, and that we really *were* in the past to them, how would you show this to be false? When you consider traveling to another planet, you would say doppler makes the other planets time *appear* faster until you reach it, and I would argue its time *actually* speeds up. Now this is the same situation with SR but in reverse with you and I perceiving the same mathematically identical effects as different things.

Comment: @Spencer I think the root of your problem is that you are not thinking clearly about the meaning of the word illusion. If you stand at a distance from me, the image you form on my retina is smaller than the image you would form if you were closer to me. That is a real physical effect, and is not an illusion. If I assumed you had physically shrunk, that would be an illusion- I would be confusing you being small with you being far away, and in that respect I am reminded of Father Doogal.

Comment: Likewise if I hold a metre rule parallel with you plane of vision and then rotate it, the projection of its length on your field of view shrinks. That is a real physical effect. If you interpreted it as meaning that the rule had shrunk, that would be an illusion.

Comment: Then if you consider that reciprocal time dilation means that my clock is running slower than yours and your clock is running slower than mine, then that is even worse than an illusion- that's a logical impossibility. But reciprocal time dilation doesn't mean that at all- your watch continues to tick off a second every second as does mine. Time dilation means that time in your frame is out of synch in mine and vice versa. If we stop moving relative to each other, the effect disappears.